# Google Maps API not working in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, google-maps

If I copy and paste the [google maps api example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map) in a html file and open the file it works:

[image]

However, if I put it in a blade file in Laravel and open it, then its not working. The window is blank and in the console I find the error

> TypeError: a is null
>   [Learn More]

The only thing that I did was to copy and paste the content to `test.blade.php` and created a route

```
Route::get('/test', function(){
  return view('test');
});
```

This is the content of my `test.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
       #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=**mysupersaveapikey**&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: Is the key you entered provided by google ?

Comment: @RobBiermann Yes the key is provided by google. I have replaced my key with `**mysupersaveapikey**` in the here shown code. The strange thing is that its working in a plane html file but not in Laravel.

Comment: Open the source in your browser for the page that is not working and compare the exact actual html the browser is seeing with the one that works.

Comment: I just run this code on fresh copy of laravel 5.6, it's run fine using blade file. Better verify you code on fresh copy of laravel project library and debug step by step. Check onec aspects of CORS.

Answer (score 1):

I recomment use dedicated api for google maps in Laravel project:
https://github.com/egeloen/ivory-google-map

```
use Ivory\GoogleMap\Helper\Builder\ApiHelperBuilder;
use Ivory\GoogleMap\Helper\Builder\MapHelperBuilder;
use Ivory\GoogleMap\Map;

$map = new Map();

$mapHelper = MapHelperBuilder::create()->build();
$apiHelper = ApiHelperBuilder::create()
    ->setKey('API_KEY')
    ->build();

echo $mapHelper->render($map);
echo $apiHelper->render([$map]);
```

Good luck!